# Lining up Drop Down items with parent menu

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a menu bar that has a drop down when hovering over the item.  So far everything works as it should except for the final lining up.  Instead of lining the drop downs directly under the parent item it lines each one up in the same spot at the far left item.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJZkI.png) one appears where it should. But [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggblq.png) and the next one still appears where the first one does.

I have tried to fix this by messing with the position on the inner drop down items and also have tried using an ul instead of a div.

**CSS:**

```
/*MENU*/
ul.menu
{
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
ul.menu li
{
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.menu li a
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #0065BD;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
ul.menu li a:hover
{
    background-color: #005299;
}

ul.menu div {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    border: solid 1px #A4A4A4;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

ul.menu div a {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #005299;
}

ul.menu div a:hover {
    background: #80B2DE;
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="/Application/Index" onmouseover="openDD('appDD')" onmouseout="closeTime()">Applications</a>
        <div id="appDD" onmouseover="cancelClose()" onmouseout="closeTime()">
            @Html.ActionLink("View Applications", "Index", "Application")
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Application", "Create", "Application")
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Report/Index" onmouseover="openDD('repDD')" onmouseout="closeTime()">Reports</a>
        <div id="repDD" onmouseover="cancelClose()" onmouseout="closeTime()">
            @Html.ActionLink("View Reports", "Index", "Report")
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Report", "Create", "Report")
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Parameter/Index" onmouseover="openDD('parDD')" onmouseout="closeTime()">Parameters</a>
        <div id="parDD" onmouseover="cancelClose()" onmouseout="closeTime()">
            @Html.ActionLink("View Parameters", "Index", "Parameter")
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Parameters", "Create", "Parameter")
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Users", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:** Used to open and close the drop down.

```
var timeout = 100;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddItem = 0;

function openDD(id) {
    cancelClose();
    closeDD();

    ddItem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddItem.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function closeDD() {
    if (ddItem) {
        ddItem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function closeTime() {
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(closeDD, timeout);
}

function cancelClose() {
    if (closetimer) {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = 0;
    }
}

document.onclick = closeDD;
```

The question is what is incorrect or needs to be added in order to get the drop down to line directly up with its main list item?  Also, CSS is not my forte so please let me know if there is a better way to do any of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in Dan's answer, you need your `position: absolute` inside a `position: relative`.
Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p8j8zehs/

Or look at this snippet:

```css
.menu-container {
  display: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.menu-container:hover ul.menu {
  display: block;
}
ul.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <span>Menu 0</span>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <span>Menu 1</span>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <span>Menu 2</span>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <span>Menu 3</span>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up using basically this but instead of the ul I used divs.

Answer (score 0):

Needs `position: relative` and `display: inline-block` on the list items. The `position: absolute` on the dropdown means it's looking further up the DOM for somewhere to position itself.

Comment: More specifically, an object with `position: absolute` will position itself according to the first parent element which is not `position: static` (which is the default for all DOM elements). Therefore, you want to always place the `position: absolute` elements inside a `position: relative` parents and not the other way around - like you have in your code.

Comment: Generally, the pattern is ul>li should be relative, and the drop down div absolute, that way, any sizing/positioning on the div is relative to the list. Normally you'd do top:100%, which will push it below the anchor